# MS SQL - Show values of dynamic length

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have a column called `command` in my table where information is stored about e-mails that should be sent out by the system.

The data looks like this:

```
<_email><property name="To">test@test.se;test@tester.se;test@test.com</property><property name="From">sender@sender.se</property>
<_email><property name="To">test@test.se</property><property name="From">sender@sender.com</property>
```

I want to use a select statement to only display the e-mail addresses of those who will receive the e-mail. By doing this, the output should look like this:

Example row 1:

```
test@test.se;test@tester.se;test@test.com
```

Example row 2:

```
test@test.se
```

I can't use `substring` since the e-mail addresses varies in length. I assume that it's possible to achieve this somehow by using regular expressions, but I cannot manage to resolve it.

Can you please help me out?

Thanks!

/ Krustofski

Comment: I think you should create a function to split each email

Comment: Could you provide us with some sample xml value from your column, so we can build something out of it?

Comment: I have updated the question so that you can copy the example strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CharIndex function in order to retrieve the start and the end of your string, and use a little math to execute the substring:

```
Select Substring(MyColumn, 
                 CharIndex('<property name="To">', MyColumn) + 20,
                 CharIndex('</property>', MyColumn) - 
                 CharIndex('<property name="To">', MyColumn) - 20
                )
From MyTable
```

I tested with your table values, and it works.

Comment: This resolved my problem, thank you so much for your help! :-)